# Generating edge cases in programming puzzles

Tags: tips, programming-puzzle

Not exactly sure if it belongs in this site, but I always have trouble thinking of all the certain edge cases in any kind of competitive programming or puzzles.

For example, take this kind of problem

> Find the size of the smallest list of squares that add up to n
>
> `f(16)-> 1 (16)`
> `f(17)-> 2 (16+1)`

One intuitive approach would be to take the largest square that fits into n, subtract, and taking the remainder and applying the function on that until n<4. This doesn't work as soon as you go to

`f(18)-> 2 (9+9)` rather than `f(18)-> 3 (16+1+1)`

While those edge cases may be easier to derive, many times edge cases will not be as intuitive. What are some general guidelines of finding such edge cases?

Comment: This is not a programming challenge, but a question about programming challenges, so it should go on meta, I think.

Comment: @Grimy Personally I'd disagree, since meta is for questions about this site, not about questions about programming challenges. The [tag:tips] tag is a good example of that kind of post being on topic here. However, I think this is irreparably broad as it is. If this were about a specific type of challenge or something, it might fit. Of course, for single challenges we have the sandbox to help with things like this.

Comment: I too think this might be better suited to Meta as it *is* about programming challenges; specifically how to think of  edge cases. Unfortunately, I do also think it's too broad as there is no "catch-all" answer; edge cases are, in general, specific to each challenge.